# A java class for throwing exception

Tags: java, exception

So this is not an error but rather a thought, I have a java class, Jform1, which is a JForm. I am trying to take only double values in to the 3 textfields and then do some computation with these numbers. But if the user fails to enter the double values and enters any characters I want to throw an exception, not just display that the it is a char and not valid either in a label or a dialogbox. 
So I want to create a *entered_Valuenotvalid* exception class how do I do that? I can't even think of how to do that, mainly because this is a seprate class itself and then the Jform is a seprate class so if error happens here then i have to get the exception from the *entered_Valuenotvalid* class.

the only thing I can think of is extending the *entered_Valuenotvalid* class, or is there a better way to do that.

Comment: Why not just restrict your users from entering anything other than numerals?

Comment: No cause my users are what you can consider as totally computer illiterates and they will be thinking something wrong with the code itself, I don't want to project that.

Comment: How is throwing an exception going to help? An exception by it's nature is an indication of an unexpected program state. You've already stated that you only want to enter numeric values, this is a known state and one you can test (at multiple different levels). How do you intend to handle this exception? Terminate the application? Show an error message? Ignore it completely??

Comment: If I was an illiterate end user, I would be frightened at the sight of an exception stack trace.

Comment: @MadProgrammer throwing exception to a label below in the JForm where the other 3 textfields are located. So what I want to do is create a exception handling class for the wrong values entered and the return from the entered_Valuenotvalid will return a string message.

Comment: You do realize that you're in an event driven environment. Validation of the field needs to take place in response to some event. Wrapping the field in a `try/catch` isn't going to achieve what you want.

Comment: @oh yes I forgot to mention that there is indeed a button for the event to kick in, did not mention that in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exception is just a subclass of Throwable.  Create the class you want, choose which JDK exception to subclass (probably IllegalArgumentException), create an instance, and `throw` it.